# Flutter call http requests from a unit\widget test without mocking

Tags: flutter, integration-testing, flutter-test

I have an app that follows MVC+service architecture. The service layer makes the http requests for rest APIs. However the response of the http requests change intermittently which cause my models to change or else random crashes in my app. SO to capture the change in these APIs I want to write some automated tests which can tell me exactly what changed. A sample test case is as following:

```
test("login_valid", () async {
    final loginData = LoginData(
      email: "abc@gmail.com",
      password: "123"
    );
    final parameters = loginData.toJson();

    var json = await httpService.post(parameters);
    var loginResponse = LoginResponse.fromJson(json);

    expect(loginResponse.status, "OK");
  });
```

**However, the above code throws `SocketException` upon run. I know this exception is thrown when `INTERNET` permission is not given in `AndroidManifest.xml` but I don't know how to set this for unit\widget tests.**

P.S. I can't mock the service layer using `mockit` or similar framework because the whole point is to test my service layer which doesn't have any business logic but just provides network integration.

Any solution or suggestion will be really helpful. I am okay with other approaches to achieve the same intent also, if there are any.

Comment: Can you share the stacktrace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check this or the gihub issue discussion pointed there
https://timm.preetz.name/articles/http-request-flutter-test

Comment: Amazing. Glad to see that, there are others who want the same as well

Comment: I tested the exact same code. copy pasted. flutter 2.0.0. IT DOESN"T WORK. Why do the flutter team doesn't allow HTTP requests in testing or just real async code in general?

Comment: This is especially useful when you don't handle the backend code, you can sniff out problems early :)